# Vistual Studio: __debugbreak() doesn't offer the option of debugging a program

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

On most of my machines if I have a __debugbreak(); statement in my program Windows will pop up a dialog saying "dummyService.exe has stopped working. Windows can checkonline for a solution to the problem" and shows three options underneath:
- "Check online for a solution and close the program"
- "Close the program"
- "Debug the program"

This is very useful when you want to debug services that arelaunched by other programs. I don't remember doing anything special to get this behavior on my system. On another machine with a similar configuration, when the service is launched I don't get the usual dialog with these 3 options, instead the dialog simply says "dummyService.exe has stopped working. Windows is checking for a solution to the problem." and shows a progress bar. No options are shown. After a few seconds, the progress bar stops and a second dialog pops up saying "Do you want to send more information about the problem?".

This happens on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 with Visual Studio Ultimate SP 1 installed. I suspect that this machine is missing either some registry setting or some options in Visual Studio that enables this debugger attach behavior.

Any tips on how to fix this annoying behavior would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Florin

Answer (score 1):

You need to set visual studio (or any other debugger) as the default JIT debugger. This can be done via tools -> options -> debugging -> Just-In-Time, then selecting native and managed and clicking ok

Comment: It was selected. I unselected it, apply, select it again and after OK still did not work.